# React Navigation page transition animation is not showing when i render React Native Vision Camera

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, android-transitions, react-native-vision-camera

I am developing a mobile application with React Navigation and React Native Vision Camera.

I am using native-stack and added the animation to each `Stack.Screen`.

```
  <Stack.Screen
    ...
    options={{animation: 'slide_from_right',...}}
   />
```

They are working well until i navigate user back from `ScanScreen`, which contained a react native vision camera component.

My working flow is `Home -> Scan -> Result -> back to Home`.

The animation is working when i navigate to `ScanScreen`, but if i call `goBack()` in `ScanScreen`, or call `popToTop()` in `ResultScreen`, the animation will be gone and the app looks like stucked little bit.

Here is the code of my `ScanScreen`

```
const ScanScreen = ({route, navigation}) => {
  const {locations} = route.params;

  // permission
  const {hasPermission, requestPermission} = useCameraPermission();
  // if camera page is active
  const isFocussed = useIsFocused();
  const isForeground = useIsForeground();
  const isActive = isFocussed && isForeground;

  // camera torch control
  const [torch, setTorch] = useState('off');
  // get device
  const device = useCameraDevice('back');
  // inititalization
  const [isCameraInitialized, setIsCameraInitialized] = useState(false);
  const onInitialized = useCallback(() => {
    console.log('Camera initialized!');
    setIsCameraInitialized(true);
  }, []);

  const codeScanner = useCodeScanner({
    codeTypes: ['qr', 'ean-13'],
    onCodeScanned: codes => {
      onQRCodeScan({codes});
    },
  });

 useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
      if (!hasPermission) {
        requestPermission();
      }
      return () => {
    //    setIsCameraReady(false);
      };
    }, []),
  );

     {device != null && (
        <Camera
          style={{flex: 1}}
          device={device}
          isActive={isActive}
          onInitialized={onInitialized}
          codeScanner={codeScanner}
          torch={torch}
        />
      )}
})
```

I am thinking if the vision camera is too heavy? or maybe i am wokring with a wrong lifecycle. I have not try it on IOS yet.

I tried to deactivate the camera before leaving the page, however the transitionStart is not fired after i can `goBack()`

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('transitionStart', (e) => {
    // Do something
  });

  return unsubscribe;
}, [navigation]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this on you `Stack.Navigator` you should not to used on your every screen.

like:

```
<Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Tabs" screenOptions={screenOptions}>
  <Stack.Screen
    name={Route.SPECS_FEATURES}
    component={SpecAndFeatures}
    options={{headerShown: false, gestureEnabled: false}}
  />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

**screenOptions**

```
const screenOptions = {
  cardStyle: {backgroundColor: colors.background, opacity: 1},
  headerShadowVisible: false,
  headerBackTitleVisible: false,
  headerTitleAlign: 'center',
  gestureDirection: 'horizontal',
  gestureEnabled: false,
  cardStyleInterpolator: CardStyleInterpolators.forHorizontalIOS,
  headerTitleStyle: {color: 'white', justifyContent: 'center'},
  transitionSpec: {open: config,close: closeConfig},
};
```

My **config**

```
const config = {
  animation: 'spring',
  config: {
    stiffness: 1000,
    damping: 100,
    mass: 3,
    overshootClamping: false,
    restDisplacementThreshold: 0.01,
    restSpeedThreshold: 0.01,
  },
};
```

My **closeConfig:**

```
const closeConfig = {
  animation: 'timing',
  config: {
    duration: 400,
    stiffness: 1000,
    damping: 500,
    mass: 100,
    overshootClamping: false,
    restDisplacementThreshold: 0.5,
    restSpeedThreshold: 0.5,
  },
};
```

If you want to change the navigation animation style you should have to change in `cardStyleInterpolator: CardStyleInterpolators.forHorizontalIOS` it provide many default animation that you want and also you can update in your **config** or **closeConfig** to change animation style.

For more details you can visit [CardStyleInterpolators](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#cardstyleinterpolators)

Comment: Hi Noah, i am using native-stack and this kind of configs you have mentioned are not suitable for me. However, i am going to try to use "stack" with your way instead of "native-stack" and see if it is better.